# aperte work flow import bpm file

Tags: xml, jar, business-process-management

I want to build a bpm process and deploy in aperte workflow. I have made the files i mention in the end of the document and i need to know any way to make a jar file from these files in order to deploy the jar into aperte workflow.

[Here is the link](https://github.com/bluesoft-rnd/aperte-workflow-core/wiki/Process-bundle-overview) where I found the instructions for making the files

Answer (score 0):

The best way to develop a bpm for Aperte is using AperteModeler.  It has in built feature to bundle and deploy the jar in Aperte Workflow.  Jars are deployed as osgi-plug ins.
follow the steps to build a workflow in AperteModeler, 
https://github.com/bluesoft-rnd/aperte-workflow-core/wiki/Sample-process-with-Aperte-Modeler